# Очки за игру не прибавляются к деньгам

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне надо что бы за очки прибавлялись деньги в меню, я прировнял очки к переменной в которую сохраняется деньги, которые потом прибавляются к деньгам в меню.

```
    public static int  NewMoney;
    public static int score = 0;
    private void Start()
    {        
        score = 0;
        NewMoney = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("NewMoney");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("NewMoney",NewMoney);
        GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = score.ToString();
        NewMoney = score;
    }
```

А в скрипте Money переменная NewMoney прибавляется к переменной money, но после игры показываются нули

```
[SerializeField] private Text moneyText;
    public static int money;

    private void Start()
    {       
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");       
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {         
        money += Score.NewMoney;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money",money);
        moneyText.text = money.ToString();
    }
```

Почему так может быть и как это исправить?

Comment: `переменная NewMoney прибавляется к переменной money` - ага, но результат нигде не сохраняется

Comment: А как же PlayerPrefs,  я же туда сохранил переменную

Comment: Эта переменная же не содержит результат сложения.

Comment: Ну я попробовал добавить  ```money += Score.NewMoney; ``` не работает

Comment: Тогда код со своими попытками надо было приводить в вопросе.

Comment: Ну вот я и исправил.

Comment: А теперь в `PlayerPrefs` сохраняется старое значение `money`...

Comment: А как тогда написать? Вы что то еще писали после ```money```?

Comment: Надо сначала посчитать новое значение, а потом сохранять его в PlayerPrefs

Comment: Ну вот я поменял а значение все ровно не выгружается.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что когда игрок умирал время становилось ```Time.timeScale = 0f```, и деньги не могли прибавляться

Comment: Спасибо за ответы